# JDK source override Maven local repository

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-8, maven-plugin

I'm trying to run my company's source code in my local machine, and in oppose to my team mates, it doesn't run.
We did a little comparison, and we've noticed that my team can see the source code of the file where the exception happened, and I can't (in this case it is org.mozilla.javascript.SOME_CLASS)
I did a little digging, and I've noticed that when I try to open declaration, I get the "source not found" page, and I see the it tries to get the source from my JDK folder, instead of my Maven's local repository, where the source exists

What can I do to make Maven's repository higher priority?

Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the issue
Apparently this extra jar file that was part of the JDK and had "org.mozilla.javascript", was actually an extension
I don't know how it got there, but it was found at /Library/Java/Extensions, and I just deleted the file, so Eclipse must go to Maven's repository for "org.mozilla.javascript.*" classes